# Printing on the same line and on a new line simultaneously

Tags: python, printing

I am trying to print an output couple of times on row number 1 and then print it on a new line. I know I should use the for loop, but somehow I can not print the output I would like to. Here is an example:

```
n =int(input())

for i in range (0,4):
    for j in range (0,3):
        print(n, end=" ")
```

Expected output - 4 rows and 3 columns:

Actual output - 1 row and 12 columns:

Comment: Try add `print()` in first loop...at the end...

Comment: `for i in range(4): print(' '.join(f'{n}' for _ in range(3))`

Answer (score 1):

An empty `print()` at the end of the loop will fix:

```
for i in range (0,4):
    for j in range (0,3):
        print(n, end=" ")
    print()      # <---
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried to solve it for more than one hour on my own and I was close, but not enough.

Answer (score 1):

Add additional print for the outer for loop. The below code should work.

```
for i in range(0, 4):
    for j in range(0, 3):
        print(10, end=" ")
    print()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
n =int(input())

for i in range (0,4):
    for j in range (0,3):
        print(n, end=" ")
    print()
```

Answer (score 1):

At the end of the inner loop, put a blank print, to reset the `end=" "`

```
n = int(input())

for i in range(4):
    for j in range(3):
        print(n, end=" ")
    print()
```

*When your `range` starts with `0`, you can omit it as I have done.*